# Aymptotic complexity of C(n,2)

Tags: asymptotics, combinations

If I have to iterate over some code n choose 2 times what is the asymptotic complexity? Let's assume that the inner loop is runs in O(n)

```
For each combination in C(n,2)
  do something in O(n) time
Next
```

Comment: What do you want to see? $C(n, 2) = n / 1 * (n-1) / 2$ - for me it is 3 arithmetic operations, does it count as $O(1)$?

Comment: If you want to answer the body ,otoh, then $C(n,2) = O(n^2)$. So overall $O(n^3)$

Comment: Thanks, I (slowly) came to this conclusion